# How to include a template in twig from another directory?

Tags: symfony, silex

I am using silex to develop some app and I have all my template in `/views` folder.

```
views
  layout.twig
  header.html
  content.html
  footer.html
```

But, I would like to create another folder in views, like `home/` `about/` ... and call the `layout.twig` folder from within those folders. For example, in `views/home/` folder, I would have `about.twig` and do this.

```
{% extends 'layout.twig'%}
{% block content %}
     {% include 'header.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

But, I am lost on how to about do this. The doc does not mention any of this.

Comment: try relative path, like `{% include 'home/header.html' %}`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have them in bundles? If so its like this:

```
{% extends "AcmeDemoBundle::layout.html.twig" %}
```

This takes the *layout.html.twig* from whichever bundle you specify in the *Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views* folder

Answer (score 1):

If all your templates are in view directory you can include like this:

```
{% extends 'layout.twig'%}
{% block content %}
     {% include 'headers/header.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

In this case, header.html  is in views/headers/header.html.

And the twig load templates from view directory, for example.

```
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(APP_DIR . '/views');
```